# React hook useState not updating state as desired?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I understand that calls to useState functions are asynchronous, but I'm having an issue with a click event and a subsequent function call where my state is not updating as needed.

Currently, I fire  an onClick event for three buttons(first, next, last). Based on which is clicked - I want to update the state of my useState hook that controls the current active page:

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
```

Here is the onClick event:

```
const firstNextLast = (event) => {
    if (event.target.name === 'first' && page !== 0) {
        setPage((prevPage) => 0);
    } else if (event.target.name === 'next' && page !== totalPages) {
        setPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1);
    } else if (event.target.name === 'last') {
        setPage((prevPage) => totalPages);
    }
    fetchFirstNextLast();
};
```

Here is the function fetchFirstNextLast():

```
const fetchFirstNextLast = () => {
    const params = {
        area: uriEncodeGJ.current,
        page,
        size: pageSize,
    };
    getEGMModelsWithin(gravitationalModel[0], params)
    .then((data) => {
        setGridData(data);
        setSuccess(true);
        setPage(data.data.pageNumber);
        setPageSize(data.data.pageSize);
        updateLat(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        setGridData(err);
        setSuccess(false);
    });
};
```

The issue with this is that the value for `page` isn't updated when I call fetchFirstNextLast(); I even attempted passing in fetchFirstNextLast() in as a callback to setPage() like so:

```
const firstNextLast = (event) => {
    if (event.target.name === 'first' && page !== 0) {
        setPage((prevPage) => 0, fetchFirstNextLast());
    } else if (event.target.name === 'next' && page !== totalPages) {
        setPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1, fetchFirstNextLast());
    } else if (event.target.name === 'last') {
        setPage((prevPage) => totalPages, fetchFirstNextLast());
    }
};
```

None of these attempts have worked. Also, I checked to see if I'm using setPage() to return the state back to 0 anywhere else in the program, so it's a not a bug of that sort. Admonishment would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

State updates in React are handled asynchronously, so `page` may not be updated when you call `fetchFirstNextLast`. It should work if you pass `fetchFirstNextLast` as a callback like so:

```js
const firstNextLast = (event) => {
    if (event.target.name === 'first' && page !== 0) {
        setPage((prevPage) => 0, fetchFirstNextLast);
    } else if (event.target.name === 'next' && page !== totalPages) {
        setPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1, fetchFirstNextLast);
    } else if (event.target.name === 'last') {
        setPage((prevPage) => totalPages, fetchFirstNextLast);
    }
};
```

Notice how the second parameter of `setPages` is just the function, instead of the result of invoking the function.